# How can i implement hash table that contains singly linked lists inside it`s items?

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable

I write my coursework which theme is system of testing. Its meaning is that the user will be able to pass other sets of tests and write their own tests. Firstly i need to create data types of my program.

I come up with hash table which will store tests-items that constain test topic and singly linked lists of questions and answers.

Here my datatypes, but i don`t know how to connect it with each other.

```cpp
#include <string>

/* One test set */
class Testlist {

    struct node {
        string question;
        string answers[4];
        node *next;
    };

public:

    Testlist();
    /* num - marker of the question or one of the answers */
    void Addquestion(string name, int num); 

};

class Test: public Testlist {
    /* maximum number of tests */
    static const int tablesize = 100;

    /* Member of the hash-table */
    struct item {
        string testname; /* Test name */
        Testlist *set; /* Set of questions and answers to them */
        Test *next;
    };

    /* Hash table of tests */
    item *testtable[NHASH];
public:

    Test();
    unsigned int hash(string key);
    void AddItem(string name, int create);

};
```

How can i work with next pointer of singly linked list in this case? Please explain me how can i implement it correctly.

Comment: Why do you think you need a _singly linked_ list? Doesn't a `std::vector` provide everything you need?

Comment: `struct Question { std::string question; std::vector<std::string> answers;}; using Test = std::map<std::string, std::vector<Question>>`.

Comment: @RolandIllig but should it be necessary to use the map as in the @molbdnilo`s comment below?

Comment: @CyberFlex Yes, a `std::map` is still necessary. But not a singly linked list. And whether you use a hash table or a sorted table shouldn't matter as well. Therefore your question title is overly specific.